# matching then fixed effects

Tags: time-series, panel-data, matching, treatment-effect

I have an unbalanced panel over time. Agents are sometimes in the panel and sometimes not. The sample share of certain groups (e.g. females) varies a lot over time (little at the start, more at the end).

I want to perform a treatment effect analysis based on matching using as gender as the “treatment”. Matching is usually done on a cross section, so should I just use one (representative) time point for the analysis or use averages over time of agents and controls to run the treatment effect analysis? or something else?

Thereafter I was hoping to do fixed effects analysis (to capture unobserved characteristics) using the weights from the first matching.

Is this legitimate? Can anyone point me to a paper where matching then fixed effect regression has been done? Thanks !

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your research design and your dependent variable?